# Change the URL of the WSDL

Tags: wsdl, ejb

I have an EJB which I hosted as a webservice the URL is something like

http://<>:7005/PurgeReportSessionEJBBean/PurgeReportSessionEJBBeanService?WSDL

Now I want to change it to

http://<>:7005/**jasperserver-pro**/PurgeReportSessionEJBBean/PurgeReportSessionEJBBeanService?WSDL

What should I do in the EJB so that the WSDl URL changes as above

Answer (score 0):

If you're declaring the webservice via the `@WebService` annotation, then you can specify `@WebService(wsdlLocation="http://...:7005/jasperserver-pro/...")`.  There is a similar attribute on the `@WebServiceProvider` annotation.